# Consolidate data from multiple worksheets into one sheet

Tags: excel, vba, consolidation

I am having trouble with writing a macro that could consolidate specific data range R10C1:R26C2 from multiple sheets in active workbook as i have to write macro physically for lets say 14 sheets as you can see from example. is there a way where the macro can pick any number of sheets within the active workbook within that data range and consolidate the data( i need to sum the data within the data range). And also i have to paste the same formula 3 times to make sure that headings of the tables (top row) and left row gets copied properly. Please help me, any help would be much appreciated.

[image: this is the data set]

```
Sub Macro15()    
    Sheets.Add

    ActiveSheet.Select
    Range("A1").Select

    Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("Sheet4!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (2)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (3)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (4)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (5)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (6)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (7)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (8)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (9)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (10)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (11)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (12)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (13)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (14)!R10C1:R26C2"), _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False

    Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("Sheet4!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (2)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (3)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (4)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (5)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (6)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (7)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (8)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (9)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (10)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (11)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (12)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (13)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (14)!R10C1:R26C2"), _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=False, CreateLinks:=False

    Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("Sheet4!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (2)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (3)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (4)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (5)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (6)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (7)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (8)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (9)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (10)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (11)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (12)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (13)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (14)!R10C1:R26C2"), _
    Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False

    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-228
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 23.88
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 41.25
    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 47.88
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 16.5
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Selection.Consolidate` methods are threefold! Any reason? To that affect, `Consolidate` uses an Array, so if your references are manually entered, put them in an Array variable, so you can easily pass it along within your Routine, or other Routines.

Comment: And, `Dim` all your needed variables, and don't use `Selection` *unless* you're going to pick your ranges manually.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: thank you and can you please advise how can i get to Dim sheets as at times there can be more than 300 sheets that i would have to consolidate the same array R10C1:R26C2.

Answer (score 0):

I will try and answer here, but please fill in gaps for your 'paste' *ask*.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro15()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim arrRange()

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

arrRange = Array("Sheet4!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (2)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (3)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (4)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (5)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (6)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (7)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (8)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (9)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (10)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (11)!R10C1:R26C2", _
"Sheet4 (12)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (13)!R10C1:R26C2", "Sheet4 (14)!R10C1:R26C2")

Set ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add

With ws2
    .Range("A1").Consolidate arrRange, xlSum, True, True, False
End With

Application.ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-228
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 23.88
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 41.25
ws.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 47.88
ws.Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 16.5

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the reason the "Selection.Consolidate methods are threefold!" due to the fact that i wanted "Department Column" to be copied when table gets consolidated  i don't know as the R10C1:R26C1 are all headings that repeat without changes and its only R10C2:R26C2 that changes in every sheet (numbers that need to be consolidated,) so i did not know how to run the routine. I have run this macro but it seems not to copy "R10C1"- (which is the  heading "department") other heading in the column from R11C1 till R26C1 have all been copied.

Comment: and how can i get to Dim sheets as at times there can be more than 300 sheets that i would have to consolidate the same array R10C1:R26C2. i will really appreciate  your help as you would know i have very basic vba skills